# Can't connect to separate database

Tags: wordpress, database, installation

Trying a new install of CiviCRM 5.3.9 using a separate Wordpress database. Wordpress, MySQL and PHP are confirmed required versions. Path is definitely correct using mysql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:3306/DB   but throws errors when I click Apply.

- Error     Database    CiviCRM InnoDB support  Could not determine if MySQL has InnoDB support. Assuming none.
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL AutoIncrementIncrement    Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL Lock Tables   Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL Temp Tables   Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL Trigger   Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL connection    Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
- Error     Database    CiviCRM MySQL utf8mb4 Support   Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    CiviCRM Mysql thread stack  Could not connect to database
- Error     Database    db.database     The property "db.database" is not well-formed.
- Error     Database    db.username     The property "db.username" is not well-formed.
- Warning   Database    CiviCRM MySQL Version   Cannot determine the version of MySQL installed. Please ensure at least version 5.6.5 is installed.
- Warning   Database    db.password     The property "db.password" is blank. This may be correct in some controlled environments; it could also be a mistake or a symptom of an insecure configuration.

The password is entered correctly in the path. I had a previous install that used exactly the same path to a separate database that worked fine for some time, then stopped working. Is there something wrong with the CiviCRM install? Can anyone suggest why the connection is failing?

Comment: if you don't get a quick and satisfactory answer here you could also try https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress

Comment: Is this a hosted environment?  If so, talk to hosting support.

Comment: It turns out CiviCRM doesn't like database user passwords with special characters. Once I removed those characters from the password, the connection worked fine. I have not seen that information in any CiviCRM documentation. I have the same special characters in my Wordpress/MySQL database connection and it works fine.

Comment: @Scarlett thanks for the update. it would be helpful to others if you could post your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM doesn't like database user passwords with special characters - especially "#". Change password.