# Civicrm separate database login syntax

Tags: wordpress, installation, mysql, passwords

I am installing Civi on localhhost. I  want to set up a database separate to Wordpress. I am using these credentials: mysql://root:HIDDEN@localhost/cividata. The database username is root, without a password. I get the same issue as described here; [Can't connect to separate database](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/cant-connect-to-separate-database). Would it be possible for someone to tell me what the correct syntax should be? Instead of HIDDEN should I use '' Thanks.

Comment: Can you try mysql://root:@localhost/cividata
I would guess it should work with nothing between : and @

Comment: "Can you try mysql://root:@localhost/cividata I would guess it should work with nothing between : and @"

If that doesn't work, actually lose the ellipse.
mysql://root@localhost/cividata

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I set a password for the database and used that in the login script. I still haven't figured out how to do it without a password.

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be special characters in the password. Once I changed the password the connection worked fine. To connect to the database, I just changed the path in this line in civicrm-settings.php file to:

define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://username:password@localhost:3306/databasename?new_link=true');

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this sounds like the answer to a different question. Did you mean to post it as an answer to your question? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/cant-connect-to-separate-database

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question about the syntax needed on install when wanting a separate database is as follows. I struggled with this myself today, which was on a Drupal 7 site.

mysql://example_dbuser:password@localhost/example_dbname

where of course example_dbuser is the user name, password is the password without special characters and example_dbname is the separate civicrm database name.